# Where is the port number defined, which is used in JDBC hive connection string?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, derby

I have just started Hadoop and Hive programming, and I have written a Java code, which connects to a derby metastore, and gives proper output.
The connection string I defined is:

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

The program works fine, and gives me the required output.
But I would like to know where this port number 10000 is defined, and how to change this port number if required.

Comment: If any of these answers resolved your issue, please click the check mark the left of the answer to mark this question as resolved. You will be rewarded with a small amount of reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the hive related configuration details under Hive installation directory. 
File name is **hive-site.xm**l like in my case file is present under this path `/usr/hdp/current/hive-server2/conf`

There is a parameter defined with the name **hive.server2.thrift.port** in `hive-site.xml` file

```
<property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
      <value>10000</value>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

It, usually, is defined in hive configuration file, `hive-site.xml`. Check for the property `hive.server2.thrift.port`. Default value is 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answers, you dont even have to struggle searching for hive-site.xml, once you open your HiveCLI, just type in below property.

```
hive> set hive.server2.thrift.port;
```

it should give you the hiveserver2 port number.

```
hive.server2.thrift.port=10000
```

If you want to change the port number by setting the property in hive CLI

```
set hive.server2.thrift.port=10014;
```

These properties are maintained in hive-site.xml(Conf directory) which is located in the location where Hive is installed.